# .htaccess not working with backslash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all URLs to my bootstrap file `php/bootstrap.php` and include the path as an URL parameter `path`

So I wrote this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./php/bootstrap.php?path=$1 [L]
```

When I go to `localhost/abc/def/` it gets rewritten to `localhost/php/bootstrap.php?path=abc/def/` and I receive the correct parameter. But when I go to `localhost/abc/def/\` (including a backslash somewhere) it'll throw a 404 error and doesn't rewrite the URL.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't look like a problem with your htaccess file, looks like a problem with your bootstrap.php not being able to cope with a `\`.

Comment: @JonLin The bootstrap file just does `var_dump($_GET);`. I get an 404 error from the Apache server

Comment: Update: It's a Windows bug. Could not reproduce under Apache 2.2.22 on GNU/Linux. Regardless though, I'm curious too how this can be solved. The only ugly hack I can think of is making the 404 error document detect this and rewrite it that way.

Comment: Please explain, why add a backslash in a URL?

Comment: @jacouh because I don't want my website to break when people visit it, so I want to handle this error by displaying my custom error page

Comment: I typed in Google Chrome a backslash \ any where in the URL, it transforms immediately on slash /, I cannot test it...

Comment: @jacouh Most browsers do this, Firefox does not. Still, It should work. Turns out (as Luc said) to be an Apache (win) bug